# Get SOAP web service gzip enconding response from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, web-services, gzip, soapui, ole-automation

I'm trying to call a SOAP web service from SQL Server using OLE Automation stored procedures, and I've got troubles with the response which is Content-Encoding gzip.

When test the method using SOAP UI works like a charm.

[Soap UI shows response like xml. Http log shows response is gzip encoded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6X5Y.png)

When I make the call from SQL Server, I get an unexpected response like this

[XML response from SQL Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WkCi.png)

Status return is ok 200.

`GetAllResponseHeaders` doesn't include 'Content-Encoding: gzip', Soap UI does!
I included all request headers showed on SOAP UI.

Here is my code (I omitted error handling for the sake of readability)

```
DECLARE
    @URI varchar(2000) = 'http://foo/foo.wsdl',          
    @methodName varchar(50) = 'post',     
    @requestBody varchar(8000) = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:CCTwebservices"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><urn:recepcionLiberacionTatc soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><user xsi:type="xsd:string">foo</user><password xsi:type="xsd:string">foo</password><dataIn xsi:type="xsd:string"><![CDATA[foo]]></dataIn></urn:recepcionLiberacionTatc></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>',     
    @SoapAction varchar(255) = 'urn:CCTwebservices#recepcionLiberacionTatc',  
    @responseText varchar(8000);

DECLARE @objectID int    
DECLARE @hResult int    
DECLARE @source varchar(255), @desc varchar(255)     

--create object
EXEC @hResult = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @objectID OUT    
-- open the destination URI with Specified method     
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'open', null, @methodName, @URI, 'false', null, null    
-- set request headers    
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8'
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Accept-Encoding', 'gzip,deflate'
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Host', 'ws.foo`enter code here`.cl'
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Connection', 'Keep-Alive'
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'SOAPAction', @SoapAction     

declare @len int    
set @len = len(@requestBody)     
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Length', @len     
  
-- send the request     
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'send', null, @requestBody     
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'getResponseHeader', null, 'Content-Encoding' -- Return null
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'GetAllResponseHeaders' -- Response doesn't incluye 'Content-Encoding: gzip', Soap UI does!.

exec sp_OAGetProperty @objectID, 'StatusText'
exec sp_OAGetProperty @objectID, 'Status'
exec sp_OAGetProperty @objectID, 'responseText' -- return the xml show previosly

exec sp_OADestroy @objectID
```

Any help to make this work?

Comment: What was in the `Accept-Encoding` header you sent from SOAP UI? What happens if you change your code to just use `Accept-Encoding: gzip`?

Comment: From SOAP UI Accept-Encoding sends "gzip,deflate" which I replicated on my code.
I tried both "gzip" and "gzip,deflate" but didn't work